# Simple CSS dropdown appears differently across browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, submenu

Hi thanks for reading my first question here at SO.

I'm the admin for http://www.theacoutlet.com and I'm adding some content pages. I took one element from the middle nav. bar ("FIND PRODUCTS") and made it a dropdown via CSS on hover.

The CSS (below) has been validated.

The problem is this sub-menu now displays *three different ways in Firefox, IE, and Chrome*. It does not appear to me to be very complex and I am stumped. It does not display *at all* in IE, and of course most of our customers use IE.

IE: Submenu does not display at all on hover.

Firefox: Submenu displays, with a wierd list item bullet (not in the HTML!) on top, and the menu appears over the original "FIND PRODUCTS" text.

Chrome: Submenu displays perfectly, only problem is it disappears quite easily when you try to hover over new items... requires extremely fast/precise mouse movements to keep menu from disappearing.

Code is below. Thanks for reading and appreciate your help!

HTML:

```
<div class="menisell2">


<a href="search.php" class="menisell2">FIND PRODUCTS</a> <img src="images/de_26.jpg" width="1" height="22" border="0" align="middle"> 

<span class="menisell2content">

<a href="search.php"><br>SEARCH</a><br><br>

<a href="products1.php">COOLING</a><br><br>

<a href="products2.php">HEAT PUMP</a><br><br>

<a href="products3.php">DUAL FUEL</a><br><br>

<a href="products4.php">GAS HEAT</a><br><br>

<a href="products5.php">MINI SPLITS</a><br><br>

<a href="products6.php">PACKAGE UNITS</a><br><br>
</span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menisell2, .menisell2 a:visited {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    position:relative;
}

.menisell2 a:visited {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menisell2content a:visited {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.menisell2:hover  {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #CE252C;
    text-decoration: none;
} 

.menisell2 a  {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.menisell2content a  {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #4682B4;
}

.menisell2content a:hover  {

color: #CE252C;

}

.menisell2:hover .menisell2content{

visibility:visible;


}

.menisell2content{
visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
display:list-item;
font-size: 12px;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #4682B4;
}
```

Comment: The markup for this really should be a list, e.g. <ul>.

Comment: you have `.menisell2content` set up with `position: absolute`, but you haven't told the browser where to position it. try doing that

Comment: Adding <ul> and <li> unfortunately did not change the outcome. Adding position values did but in a very negative way. Any other ideas?